# unable to add data to instance of model object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two model classes like this

```
 public class PersonFullResponse
{
    public string profilePicture { get; set; }
    public string primaryMembership { get; set; }
    public List<EducationsResponse> educations { get; set; }
}
 public class EducationsResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public int StartYear { get; set; }
    public int EndYear { get; set; }
    public string Degree { get; set; }
    public object FieldOfStudy { get; set; }
}
```

as you can see first model contains a list of second model too.
and Now I am trying to create an object of this class and data data to it like this

```
   PersonFullResponse pfr = new PersonFullResponse();
                   var er = new EducationsResponse
                {
                    Degree = "",
                    SchoolName = "",
                    StartYear =11,
                    EndYear =12
                };
           pfr.educations.Add(er);
```

But this throws an error at the final step

```
    System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set educations to empty List. After it you can add members to it.

```
PersonFullResponse pfr = new PersonFullResponse {educations = new List<EducationsResponse>()};
```

Then you create PersonFullResponse instance, all properties are set to default values. Default value for List is null. So you should create new instance of the List before using it.

You can set the property either via setter or in class constructor.

Comment: I don't completely got you, Can you add a code sample?

Comment: Yes, That worked thanks for the help.I ll accept the answer as correct mean while may be you can add some more description to your answer it will help other people to understand what went wrong and why this solution :)

Comment: I update the answer to get more details about reasons of the behavior